# breezejs data.results different and wrong compared to data.httpresponse.data

Tags: breeze

The only difference between my code and the examples are that I'm using version 1.5.4 and the examples use 1.5.3.

`var query = new breeze.EntityQuery.from('resourcemgt/providers').orderByDesc('Edi').skip(0).take(10);
           unitOfWork.providers.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
                $scope.providers = data
            });`

heres an example of the code.

data.results gives me duplicates
data.httpresponse.data is correct.

Anyone venture to guess why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

Breeze released a new version last night.  Version 1.5.5 appears to have fixed this issue.